# Load content of PHP echoed link in div on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sql

I have `SELECT` data from a table from my database.This data come with links. What i want is that when i click on the link, it loads more of that data in a div instead of going to a a different page. Each links comes with an `id` from which to know data to load in the `div` from the database.Below is the code

```
<div class="pricepop"></div>
<div class="pricetab">
<table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>COMMODITIES</th>
                      <th>UNITS</th>
                      <th>INTERNATIONAL PRICE($)</th>
                      <th>TERMS</th>
                      <th>LOCAL PRICE (&#8358;)</th>
                      <th>AS AT</th>
                      <th>MARKET</th>
                      <th>Full Details</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <style>
                .table > thead > tr > th, .table > tbody > tr > td {
                    font-size: 10px !important;
                    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
                </style>
                  <?php
                  $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM commodityprices");
                  $result = $sql->execute();
                  while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
                  {
                      $id = $row['id'];
                      $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                      $name = $row['name'];
                      $unit = $row['unit'];
                      $iprice = $row['iprice'];
                      $lprice = $row['lprice'];
                      $irate = $row['irate'];
                      $lrate = $row['lrate'];
                      $terms = $row['cterms'];
                      $asat = date('d/M/Y');
                      $market = $row['market'];

                          echo '<tr>
                          <td>'.$name.'</td>
                          <td>'.$unit.'</td>';
                          if ($irate == "Down")
                          {
                              echo '
                              <td style="background: #ef5a66; color: #fff"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"> </i> '.$iprice.'</td>';
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            echo '
                            <td style="background: #28bc88; color: #fff"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"> </i> '.$iprice.'</td>';
                          }
                          echo '<td>'.$terms.'</td>';
                          if ($lrate == "Down")
                          {
                              echo '
                              <td style="background: #ef5a66; color: #fff"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"> </i> '.$lprice.'</td>';
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            echo '
                            <td style="background: #28bc88; color: #fff"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"> </i> '.$lprice.'</td>';
                          }
                          echo '<td>'.$asat.'</td>
                          <td>'.$market.'</td>
                          <td><a class="comprice" href="pricedetails.php?id='.$id.'">View more</a></td>
                          </tr>';
                  }                 
                  ?>
                </tbody>
                </table>
</div>
```

Below i have a `javascript` that loads the data from the database into the `.pricepop` on link click

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".comprice").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".pricepop").load("pricedetails.php");
    });
});
```

Below is the **pricedetails.php** code that gets the remaining price details.

```
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>COMMODITIES</th>
                      <th>TERMS</th>
                      <th>LOCAL PRICE (&#8358;)</th>
                      <th>AS AT</th>
                      <th>MARKET</th>
                      <th>Price/bag</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <style>
                .table > thead > tr > th, .table > tbody > tr > td {
                    font-size: 10px !important;
                    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
                </style>
                  <?php
                  $priceId = $_SESSION['id'];
                  $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM commodityprices WHERE id = ?");
                  $sql->bindParam(1, $priceId, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
                  $result = $sql->execute();
                  while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
                  {
                      $id = $row['id'];
                      $name = $row['name'];
                      $iprice = $row['iprice'];
                      $lprice = $row['lprice'];
                      $lrate = $row['lrate'];
                      $terms = $row['cterms'];
                      $asat = date('d/M/Y');
                      $market = $row['market'];
                      $priceperbags = $row['priceperbags'];

                          echo '<tr>
                          <td>'.$name.'</td>';
                          echo '<td>'.$terms.'</td>';
                          if ($lrate == "Down")
                          {
                              echo '
                              <td style="background: #ef5a66; color: #fff"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"> </i> '.$lprice.'</td>';
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            echo '
                            <td style="background: #28bc88; color: #fff"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"> </i> '.$lprice.'</td>';
                          }
                          echo '<td>'.$asat.'</td>
                          <td>'.$market.'</td>
                          <td class="comprice">'.$priceperbags.'</td>
                          </tr>';
                  }
                  ?>
                </tbody>
                </table> 
</div>
```

The issue now is that no matter the link i click on from the echoed `php` data, the data displayed in the `.pricepop` is the details last `echo` link.

How can i fix this such that when i click on a link, details gotten from `id` of that link is `echo` and displayed in the `.pricepop`.

Answer (score 0):

You must use AJAX POST or GET statemant to get what you need. Simple jQuery `.load()` can't help you.

In basics, you must do some kind of pagination to load or append new data.

Here is examples:

http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-infinite-scroll-pagination-using-jquery-ajax-exampleexample.html
http://phppot.com/php/ajax-pagination-with-php/

Comment: Thanks but how can infinite scroll solve this issue?